# Symfony Doctrine - set time zone

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have multiple Symfony applications running on the same sever, and every application may need a different time zone.

For php, it's doable by using different fpm pools and setting the time zone in the pool configuration:

```
php_admin_value[date.timezone] = America/New_York
```

but for MySQL, I need to issue the statement:

```
"SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';
```

as the first query after connected, or add to the $options array in the PDO constructor:

```
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';"
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Don’t go this way. Operate in UTC everywhere, in the application format dates using appropriate time zone instead. This approach is much easier and cleaner. In Twig bundle configuration you can even set the time zone so Twig does the conversion for you.

Comment: Have not tried it myself but the Doctrine dbal options config should allow you to set the time zone.  But I agree that going with utc is the better approach.

Comment: Another approach would be a high priority kernel request listener which would execute your set time_zone statement before anything else got going.

Comment: @emix my data is aggregated by date, I don't store times but if something happens now I store it in a column with date 2019-01-13. So the date can changes depending on what time zone I'm in

Comment: I guess the best way to go would be to calculate the date at application level and leave MySQL to utc, or set it only when there isn't any other way

Answer (score 5):

You can use PostConnect Doctrine event ... https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/events.html#postconnect-event

This is useful to configure the connection before any sql statement is executed.

An example may be:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Event\ConnectionEventArgs;

/**
 * My initializer
 */
class  MyPdoInitializerListener
{
    public function postConnect(ConnectionEventArgs $args)
    {
        $args->getConnection()
            ->exec("SET time_zone = 'America/New_York'");
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the listener to services.yaml

```
# services.yaml

    # ...

    App\EventListener\MyPdoInitializerListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postConnect }
```

Comment: Note that this solution is deprecated as of DBAL v3.5

Comment: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/3.5.x/UPGRADE.md#deprecated-extension-via-connection-events

Answer (score 2):

To extend on [SilvioQ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54164277/424381), I wrote the following snippet to inherit the time zone from the PHP environment, assuming that `date_default_timezone_set()` was previously called to set the correct time zone:

This solution has an advantage over named time zones (like `"America/New_York"`) when those named time zones are [not available within MySQL/MariaDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120945/how-do-i-resolve-this-error-error-1298-hy000-unknown-or-incorrect-time-zone) and you have no control over the server.

```php
public function postConnect(ConnectionEventArgs $args) {
    $tz = new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get());
    $offset = $tz->getOffset(new DateTime('now'));
    $abs = abs($offset);
    $str = sprintf('%s%02d:%02d', $offset < 0 ? '-' : '+', intdiv($abs, 3600), intdiv($abs % 3600, 60));
    $args->getConnection()->exec("SET time_zone = '$str'");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I had a similar problem, where the time zone from symfony/doctrine/php differed from mysql and I didn't know what side effects setting a time zone on database produces, so I calculated offset between php Datetime and now-function in mysql and set this as offset.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.5 of Doctrine DBAL, the solution proposed by SilvioQ is deprecated.

Doctrine documentation recommends implementing a middleware class for the database driver instead. An example of such implementation can be found within the DBAL code itself: [src/Logging/Middleware.php](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/69cb431ec647aa5516944ddb8496d36f6d0aba0d/src/Logging/Middleware.php)

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Changing version 3.5 to 3.6 works; https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/3.6.x/src/Logging/Middleware.php